# Laravel multi guards redirection does not work properly when the session is expired

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware, laravel-authentication

I'm testing my Laravel projects which has 3 guards. everything works fine when I log in to each guard dashboard. However, I noticed that when I don't log out for a long time and the sessions get expired and try to login again, the redirection mechanism shows a strange behavior. When I hit the login button after entering the correct credentials I don't get redirected to the dashboard. It redirects me to the other guard login page!!. I check a lot of threads here in stackoverflow but nothing worked in my situation.

These are snippets of my code

app/config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
    
    'employee' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'employees',
    ],

    'company_employee' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'company_employees',
    ],
    'truck_agency_employee' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'truck_agency_employees',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    'employees' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Employee::class,
    ],

    'company_employees' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\CompanyEmployee::class,
    ],

    'truck_agency_employees' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\TruckAgencyEmployee::class,
    ],
],
```

app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  ...$guards
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        $guard = Arr::get($guards, 0);

        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()){

            switch ($guard) {
                case 'employee':
                    return redirect()->route('employee_dashboard');
                case 'company_employee':
                    return redirect()->route('company_dashboard');
                case 'truck_agency_employee':
                    return redirect()->route('truck_agency_dashboard');
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

## Note: Auth::guard($guard)->check() always returns false and Auth::user() always returns null.

app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guards = [];

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @param  string[] ...$guards
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $this->guards = $guards;

        return parent::handle($request, $next, ...$guards);
    }

    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (!$request->expectsJson()) {
            $guard = Arr::get($this->guards, 0);
            switch ($guard) {
                case 'employee':
                    return route('employee_login');
                case 'company_employee':
                    return route('company_employee_login');
                case 'truck_agency_employee':
                    return route('truck_agency_employee_login');
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

app/Exeptions/Handler.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'current_password',
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
            //
        });
    }

    /**
    * Report or log an exception.
    *
    * @param  \Throwable  $exception
    * @return void
    *
    * @throws \Exception
    */
    public function report(Throwable $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }


    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Throwable  $exception
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     *
     * @throws \Throwable
     */
    public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }

    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['message' =>  $exception->getMessage()], 401);
        }

        $guard = Arr::get($exception->guards(), 0);

        switch ($guard) {
            case 'employee':
                $login = 'employee_login';
            break;
            case 'company_employee':
                $login = 'company_employee_login';
            break;
            case 'truck_agency_employee':
                $login = 'truck_agency_employee_login';
            break;
            default:
                $login = 'home';
            break;
        }
        return redirect()->guest(route($login));
    }

}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated, Thank you